# Создать приложение - стукач

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть задача от заказчика создать приложение "Стукач", его цель заключается в том чтобы сотрудники работающие на предприятии могли фотографировать нарушение, оставлять метку на карте и всю эту информацию отправлять своему администратору, администратор получает эти данные на свой аккаунт в приложении в виде некого списка.

Не представляю с чего начать, так как вообще я разработчик юнити, делаю игрушки. Работал конечно с фотон сервером, но как написать такое приложение на юнити представляю слабо, поэтому прошу подсказать мне ПО, видео-гаиды, было бы идеально если бы это можно было реализовать на юнити, язык C#. Всем спасибо и здоровья.

Comment: я так понимаю надо оконое приложение. или на мобилку

Comment: @Санитариум нужно именно мобильное приложение под Android

Comment: ну я бы так делал. брал карты к примеру от яндекса. отбаратывал нажатие на карту. ставил метку, есть тип метку куда можно описание добавить и вроде картинки но не уверен. брал бы координаты и описание сериализовал в json строку  отправлял на сервер  и записать а базу например и потом уже  выводить закачику данные

Comment: Вам не unity нужно, а Xamarin.Forms для клиентской части и Asp.Net Core для серверной (web api).

Comment: @Bulson спасибо за информацию, я так понял что это выполнимо по срадствам в юнити, если работать с базами данных, например отправлять пакет с информацией в базу данных, а затем из базы данных передавать эту информацию всем администраторам приложения, но такой способ не совсем правильный я так понимаю

Comment: Cтукач -> Человек с активной гражданской позицией

Answer (score 2):

1. Пишешь простенький код на php который принимает изображение + коментарий + координаты и записывает это все в БД
2. Пишешь на Ксамарине(в идеале) апликуху где есть пара полей: сделать фотку, текст коментария и сабмит. Можно и на юнити в принципе... Но на ксамарине будет лучше т.к. работать будет банально быстрее. И сама апликуха будет значительно легче.
3. Координаты подхватываешь из GPS модуля (не забудь обработать ситуацию когда GPS не включен!)
4. Просто посылаешь все эти данные на адрес того php
5. Пишешь на php простенькую страницу для отображения всего собранного мусора. Собственно простенькая таблица: изображение, текст коментария, линк на карту гугл мапс или яндекс карт. Линк генерируется просто из строки поиска, например

> https://www.google.com/maps/place/50°28'34.3"N+30°32'19.1"E

где 50°28'34.3"N+30°32'19.1"E - это координаты места взятые с GPS